# Sound and Video issues on Chromebook

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, acer, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Chromebook Acer C720. I am running into issues playing YouTube videos, as well as playing any sound.

Commands haven't worked for the sound, and I have no clue how to solve the video issue.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu restricted extras? also, please mention how are you trying to play audio and video. You have problem for playing them online (if yes in which browser) or you face the issue for local media files as well.\

Answer (score -1):

You can follow steps described in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) for troubleshooting sound problems.

And for youtube case, test your flash player plugin or better than that, make sure that you're using html5 video player.

Comment: This should be a comment as you do not offer any kind of solution to the problem. -1 This does not answer the question.